# If my friend sent a recording of his lecture; Is it against the law?

Tags: audio-video-recording, lecture-teaching-method

I don't attend university, but I would love to learn to further my IT skills, is my friend allowed to record his lecture and send it to me? Is there any law against this... Or is he free to do what he wants for example post it on YouTube?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: if it is _his_ lecture, then i think he can do whatever he likes

Comment: Who owns the copyright?

Comment: PsySp: I believe he meant his friend is a student in the course.

Comment: There are many different websites and universities that offer free courses. MIT, Stanford, etc. all offer courses online that are free. These are probably much better quality than what your friend records.

Comment: @PeytonB That's why I said _if_ because it's not clear to me if his friend is a prof. or a student.

Comment: Did he record himself or someone else?

Answer (score 6):

In the United States, the person who delivered the lecture owns the copyright if the lecture is "fixed" in tangible form.  That recording fixes the lecture in tangible form, even if the person who delivered the lecture didn't make the recording.  So, in the U.S., it's (probably) covered by copyright.  (I'm not a lawyer.)

The person who made the recording, if not the person who delivered the lecture and thus owns the copyright, absolutely shouldn't post it any place, *e.g.* on YouTube without the permission, preferably in writing, of the person who delivered the lecture.  That person should ask before sharing it with a friend; probably most professors would allow that.

Comment: +1 Aside from copyright (which this response addresses), I'd add that generally, I permit recording of my lecture for the use of the students of a course with the specific request not to distribute the lecture further. The reason is that the lecture serves specifically that particular audience. I would prepare lecture to be visible world-wide in a different way and with a different slant (and probably more meticulously, but with less flexibility in treatment). I would be very displeased to see my request ignored and would probably withdraw my permission to be filmed henceforth.

Comment: I record my own lectures, mostly to make them available to students who miss class, but doing so has the added benefit of securing copyright.  I tell my students that they may share the links to my recordings with individuals, such as the "friend" in the question, but may republish neither the links nor the recordings.  So far, no one has betrayed my trust.